# Sending Reminder Emails in SP 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, reminder, workflow-designer

I originally attempted using "Assign a task" to schedule my reminder emails if a task was not completed by the due date, but the task would not complete itself. Therefore, I need another way to send the Reviewer an email somewhere between where they are sent an email which assigns them as the Reviewer and the parallel block that waits for a change in the current item field.

I've read about the pause for duration option and then re-evaluating your conditions, but I wouldn't want to send the reminder email until 3-5 days after the original email was sent. I don't want the entire workflow to be held up for others who are also using the workflow process. (Hope that makes sense)

Here's a copy of the stage in my workflow. I have highlighted where I would need some type of condition and action.

[image: SP 2013 Workflow Stage]

Answer (score 2):

Create another workflow for sending notifications, you can store the date when the first reminder was sent and can configure notification workflow to run everyday check when first reminder was sent if it was 3/5 days ago as per your choice, you can send a second reminder.

Comment: So I'm guessing this would be a separate workflow using the same list? Also, the reminder email is dependent on a field being answered by the Reviewer. Would you just put that in there as a condition?

Comment: Yes, different WF using same list, you can have a check/condition on dependent field and decide whether to send an email or not.

Comment: You also mentioned configuring the notification workflow to run everyday to check condition of the dependent workflow. Would that be done using loop or pause for duration?

Comment: That will be done using a loop and it will pause for next day (say it runs every midnight). Since it works like a background activity it won't interfere with other WF

Comment: I didn't think to ask before, but were you saying to create a workflow using 2010 platform to integrate into the main 2013 workflow? Or is it possible to do that with 2013?

Comment: You have options to create a 2010 WF or a 2013 WF in SP designer 2013

Comment: I don't see anywhere I have mentioned 2010 WF. I just said create another WF

Comment: Yes, I know that you didn't mention a 2010 workflow. In my experience, I have only ever had to integrate a 2010 workflow into a 2013. I didn't know if there is a way to integrate a 2013 into a 2013? When I insert the "Start a List Workflow" action, it only gives me the option for SharePoint 2010 Workflow.

Comment: I think you are missing on some components, you will have to install them. Do you have SP online or SP on Prem? Refer below link for details https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219638%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: SharePoint Online